# HP - CommandView - get logs from events from command line?

Tags: command-line-interface, storage-area-network

In Hp - CommandView EVA, is there any way to get the event logs from the command line?

I'm trying to get the logs from the web interface but the button that says "get log" from the event tabs doesn't work :(

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well after some time i found out that the logs can be locate on the disk.
In this path C:\hsvmafiles

But the file that interests us is on a "binary" format that only HP can analyse...

Thanks